# How can I desaturate a video file in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, video

I have a function that can desaturate an image successfully, but now I want to desaturate an ogg video file. Here is my function:

function desaturate(img) {

```
 var img2 = Pixastic.process(img, "desaturate");
img2.onmouseout = function() {
    Pixastic.revert(this);
        threshold();
    }
}
```

Here is the embed code for my video:

```
 <video id="videotag" src="video.ogg" onclick="videoclick(this); desaturate(this)"
```

The video plays but is not desaturated by the function. I would really appreciate it if someone could help me out with this.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there's no real support for that.  But you can read about CSS filters here - http://updates.html5rocks.com/2011/12/CSS-Filter-Effects-Landing-in-WebKit .  Apparently you may be able to desaturate in Firefox (didn't work for me, though).

Comment: For Firefox you have to do the filter in SVG. See [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter] for more information.

Comment: Thanks guys I'll look into it and report back.